# Getting Error while changing a password with AdminPasswordChangeForm in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-templates

I don't have so much idea about changing the password using `AdminPasswordChangeForm`. I got a tutorial and found this snippet:

```
def user_change_password(request, id):
    form = AdminPasswordChangeForm(User, request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save()
        msg = _('Password changed successfully.')
        request.user.message_set.create(message=msg)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('..')
    else:
        form = AdminPasswordChangeForm(User)
        extra_context = {    
            'form': form,
            'change': True
        }
        return direct_to_template(request,"users/user_password_change.html",
            extra_context = extra_context)
```

Everything is fine with `url.py` and template `user_password_chage.html`. In the template level, it is showing a form with two password fields: one is password and the second is password(again). But when I click on submit button to change the password it shows the following error:

> unbound method set_password() must be called with User instance as first argument (got unicode instance instead)

I am a newbie to Django and didn't found anything regarding this form in the official docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to the form instantiation call is supposed to be a user instance, not the User class - ie it should be the actual user whose password you want to change. Presumably that's the current user, so you can get that from `request.user`:

```
form = AdminPasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am passing a id to change his/her password. So according to that i have to first find out the username associate with id and then passes that username in function?

Apart from this if i have to also change the is_staff option for same id then what should i have to do?

Comment: No, not the username, the user instance. User.objects.get(pk=my_id) would do it.

Comment: It runs successfully and what about the changing is_staff option